# How can I restrict all networking requests to a Wi-Fi connection with AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

I have a rather odd question. I want to know if it's possible to block any requests (current and future) using AFNetworking 2.0. My app needs to do something like this: if the user is not on a wifi connection -> block any requests that the app may have. 
I only found a way to block all current requests:

```
[self.manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

Any help is welcome and much appreciated

Comment: Are you supporting only iOS 7, or older versions as well?

Comment: I'm suporting  ios 6 as wel

Answer (score 4):

Since iOS 6, [`NSMutableURLRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) allows you to specify whether a request can be made over a cellular connection by calling `setAllowsCellularAccess:`. This is explained by this [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/Platform-SpecificNetworkingTechnologies/Platform-SpecificNetworkingTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH212-SW9). You will need to set this for every request you make.

With AFNetworking, the cleanest way to hook into `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is to use your own [requestSerializer subclass](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h) and override `-requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:error:` to call super and modify the request with `setAllowsCellularAccess:`.

If you are also using NSURLSession in your iOS 7 code paths, you can use an [`NSURLSessionConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html) with its `allowsCellularAccess` property set to `NO`. This is set just once per session.

Comment: Does setting `setAllowsCellularAccess` to `NO` guarantee that communication will take place over Wi-Fi if the device has both Wi-Fi and cellular connection turned on?

Comment: you can just `setAllowsCellularAccess` to YES on the NSMutableURLRequest returned by `-requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:error:` if you don't want to subclass

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be done using AFNetworking, but it seems that you can achieve this with custom `NSURLProtocol`:

[Can I block network access for a specific moment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122353/can-i-block-network-access-for-a-specific-moment?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using `AFNetworking 2.0`. Please check below links.
1. [AFNetworking + cancelAllRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583743/afnetworking-cancelallrequests)
2. [How to cancel network request with afnetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070175/how-to-cancel-network-request-with-afnetworking)
**Update:-**
I am sure you would also like to check this link:- **[AFNetworking and No Internet Connection scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253496/afnetworking-and-no-internet-connection-scenario/9255830#9255830)**

Comment: thanks for your response. cancelAllOperations method only cancels all ongoing operations. What I need is to block all future requests that the user might make.My scenario is that if the user doesn't want to use cellular data (he only wants to use wifi) then I have to block any requests that the app might make until he agrees to use cellular data in this appRight now I'm using a bool value to skip any request but this has to be done for each request individually. I was looking for something of a higher level in AFNetworking 2.0 that will not permit any future request the user might make